# Why is the calculation in the subtotal of this program incorrect?

Tags: c++

I am trying to create a C++ program that calculates sales tax for a customer and displays a receipt. For example, if you entered 10 as the first sale amount and the tax rate is 0.0825 it should display the total tax as $0.83. Why does my subtotal and total due at the end of the receipt display $10.82 when it should be $10.83?

```
//Customer Receipt

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

struct Item_Receipt
{
    double item;
    double cost;
    double tax;
    double subtotal;
};

int main()
{
    vector <Item_Receipt> Store_Receipt;
    Item_Receipt Purchase;

    //Variables
    const double item_tax = .0825; 
    double Item_Total = 0.0;
    double Tax_Total = 0.0;
    double Total_Sales = 0.0;
    int numSales = 0;

    cout << "First sales amount (Enter a 0 to stop): ";
    cin >> Purchase.item;
    Purchase.tax = Purchase.item * item_tax; 
    Purchase.subtotal = Purchase.item + Purchase.tax;
    Store_Receipt.push_back(Purchase);
    Item_Total += Purchase.item;
    Tax_Total += Purchase.tax;
    Total_Sales += Purchase.subtotal;
    numSales++;
    while (Purchase.item > 0.0)
    {
        cout << "Next sales amount (Enter a 0 to stop): ";

        cin >> Purchase.item;

        if(Purchase.item > 0.0)
        {
            Purchase.tax = Purchase.item * item_tax;
            Purchase.subtotal = Purchase.item + Purchase.tax;
            Store_Receipt.push_back(Purchase);

            Item_Total += Purchase.item;
            Tax_Total += Purchase.tax;
            Total_Sales += Purchase.subtotal;

            numSales++;
        }
        else
            cout << endl << "That was the last item being puchased.\nHere is your itemized receipt." << endl << endl;
    }
    //end while

    //Output
    cout << "----------------------------------------- " << endl;
    cout << "\tReceipt of Purchase" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------- " << endl << endl;
    cout << fixed << setprecision(2);
    cout << setw(10) << "Item Cost" <<
        setw(15) << "Item Tax" <<
        setw(15) << "Subtotal" << '\n';
    cout << "----------------------------------------- " << endl;
    for(int x=0;x<numSales;x++)
        cout << setw(8) << Store_Receipt[x].item << setw(15) << Store_Receipt[x].tax <<
        setw(15) << Store_Receipt[x].subtotal << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------- " << endl;
    cout << setw(10) << "Item Total" <<
        setw(15) << "Tax Total" <<
        setw(15) << "Total Due" << endl;
    cout << setw(8) << Item_Total << setw(15) << Tax_Total <<
        setw(15) << Total_Sales << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------- " << endl;
    cout << "\tYou purchased " << numSales << " items." << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------- " << endl;
    cout << "\tThank you! Have a nice day!" << endl;
    cout << "----------------------------------------- " << endl;
    cin >> numSales; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tip for writing a [mre]: you could have reduced your `main` function to four or five lines. **1)** Keep the definition of `item_tax`. **2)** Keep `Item_Total` but initialize it to `10` (the amount from your example scenario). **3)** Keep `Tax_Total` but initialize it with your calculation of the tax. **4)** *Optional* Keep `Total_Sales` but initialize it to `Item_Total + Tax_Total`. **5)** Stream the tax amount (and/or the sales total), demonstrating the lack of rounding. The rest of your code is not relevant to your question so could be dropped.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`setprecision(2)` doesn't mean "round to 2 decimal digits," it means "display 2 decimal digits."  The actual value is 10.825 but you're only displaying the first two decimal digits.

If you want to round away from the midpoint, you need to use [one of the rounding functions](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/math/round) on the result.

Since you want to round to the second decimal place, you have to first multiply the number by 100, then round it, then divide by 100.  You could do this with the help of a function:

```
double round_to_cents(double v) {
    return std::round(v * 100) / 100;
}
```

Then round the tax calculation:

```
Purchase.tax = round_to_cents(Purchase.item * item_tax);
```

([Demo](https://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8acd499bd257ec7e))